# Setting a bookmark (in Chrome) to activate a particular keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, gmail, bookmarks

I'm trying to hack together the ability to click on a bookmark (using Chrome) that essentially activates the keyboard shortcut "Shift + c", which I would use for Gmail to open a new window to compose a new email.

The keyboard shortcut is referenced here: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6594

I'm thinking it could be some kind of javascript URL that would go in the bookmark, but I've yet to be able to find anything based on a series of searches I've tried.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I just discovered that if you hold Shift and click the "Compose mail" button, it accomplishes what I want ... still looking for a one-click bookmark though!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new bookmark with URL set as https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#compose 
make it Go directly to the Compose New Mail section.

[image]

[image]

Add the Bookmark to the bookmarks bar for a one-click operation

Comment: this doesn't open it in a new window though. I know I could right click and then click "open in new window", but that's another step. It also opens this differently than simply popping it out like the gmail popout window allows. It entirely reloads gmail (with the blue progress bar) which is not ideal.